# LEFT JOIN dictionaries in python based on value

Tags: python, dictionary

```
#Input
dict_1 = {"conn": {"ts":15,"uid":"ABC","orig_h":"10.10.210.250"}}
dict_2 = {"conn": {"ts":15,"uid":"ABC","orig_h":"10.10.210.252"}}

#Mapper can be modified as required
mapper = {"10.10.210.250":"black","192.168.2.1":"black"}
```

I am getting each dict in a loop, in each iteration I need to check a dict against the mapper and append a flag based on match between `dict_1.orig_h` and `mapper.10.10.210.250` . I have the flexibility to define the mapper however I need.

So the desired result would be:

```
dict_1 = {"conn": {"ts":15,"uid":"ABC","orig_h":"10.10.210.250", "class":"black"}}
```

dict_2 will remain unchanged since there is no matching value in mapper.

This is kinda what I want, but it works only if `orig_h` is an `int`

```
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for d in dict_1:
    result[d[int('orig_h')]].update(d)
for d in mapper:
    result[d[int('orig_h')]].update(d)
```

Comment: i put the `class` key in quotes.

Comment: Thanks, that works. That is the desired output. Any idea on how to go about it?

Comment: see my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much explaining to be done; if the ip is in the mapper dictionary (if `mapper` has a key which is that ip) then set the desired attribute of the `dict` to the value of the key in the `mapper` dict (`'black'` here).

```
def update_dict(dic, mapper):
    ip = dic['conn']['orig_h']
    if ip in mapper:
        dic['conn']['class'] = mapper[ip]
```

which works exactly as desired:

```
>>> update_dict(dict_1, mapper)
>>> dict_1
{'conn': {'ts': 15, 'uid': 'ABC', 'orig_h': '10.10.210.250', 'class': 'black'}}
>>> update_dict(dict_2, mapper)
>>> dict_2
{'conn': {'ts': 15, 'uid': 'ABC', 'orig_h': '10.10.210.252'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the `conn` value for simplicity:

```
conn_data = dict_1['conn']
conn_data['class'] = mapper[conn_data['orig_h']]
```

Comment: what about the `dict_2` case?

Answer (score 0):

A two liner, extracting class and dict if the `'orig_h'` is in the `mapper` dictionary's keys, if it id, keep it, otherwise don't keep it, then create a new dictionary comprehension inside the list comprehension to add `'class'` to the dictionary's `'conn'` key's dictionary.

```
l=[(i,mapper[i['conn']['orig_h']]) for i in (dict_1,dict_2) if i['conn']['orig_h'] in mapper]
print([{'conn':dict(a['conn'],**{'class':b})} for a,b in l])
```

**BTW this answer chooses the dictionaries automatically**